# How to reassign a variable in reactive Flux stream?

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm sending requests to a webservice, transform the results into a large `csv` and persist the csv lines into a database.

As the requests are long running (10-20s), I want to parallelize the requests.
I collect all the data in a single `StringBuilder` that holds the transformed csv lines.

Question: if my chunks of 1000 lines is reached within the csv, how can I take the data out for persistence, while any other concurrent response will be written to a new `StringBuilder`?

Because, final variables for a stream cannot be reinitialized.

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

Flux.fromIterable(requests)
    .flatMap(req -> {
        return webClientService.send(req); //assume long running response
    }, 8) //send 8 requests in parallel, as response takes up to 10s
    .map(rsp -> {
        //convert response to csv values and add to StringBuilder
        int c = addCsv(sb, rsp);
        if (count.addAndGet(c) > 1000) {
            //TODO how can I assign a new StringBuilder,
            //so that all further finished responses will append the csv to the new builder?
            //same problem with the counter.
            
            databaseWriter.write(sb.build()); //writes the content so far to db, but not threadsafe so far
        }
        return c;
    })
    .blockLast();
```

Comment: what does `addCsv` do, and what does the stored format look like. You are getting answers you are not pleased with because your explanation is not clear enough. If you want to avoid certain things etc, please write out `ALL` requirments so that we dont have to do guesswork.

Comment: As written, `addCsv` add the results from the response as csv lines to the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to avoid side-effects entirely instead, e.g. with something like:

```java
.map(x -> toCsv(x))
.reduce((a, b) -> {
    if (length(a) < 1000) {
        return concat(a, b);
    }
    databaseWriter.write(a);
    return b;
})
.doOnNext(x -> databaseWriter.write(x))
```

Comment: But this would again mean I could not be using a global `StringBuilder`, but would produce many `String` objects. I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can use builtin operators to achieve the same result:

```
      Flux.fromIterable(requests)
            .flatMap(req -> webClientService
                    .send(req)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()), 8)// subscribeOn to subscribe from different threads
            .map(resp -> converToCsvLine(resp)) //make some transformations on the respnse
            .window(1000) //split incoming data into 1000 lines
            .flatMap(stringFlux -> stringFlux.collect(Collectors.joining("\n")))// collect last 1000
            .flatMap(s -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> writeToDb(s))) //do some logic on the collected 1000 lines
            .blockLast();
```

Comment: That would mean that I'd have to create a `String` object for each line. But that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid by using the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: You can create your own collector:  `.flatMap(stringFlux -> stringFlux.collect(StringBuilder::new,StringBuilder::append))`

Comment: Or something like `.window(1000).flatMap(stringFlux -> stringFlux.collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, resp) -> addCsv(sb, resp)))`